# Dynamic iframe corresponding to 100vh in HTML embedded link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am embedding a link to a web page using an iframe with no height or width settings. What would the iframe embed code be if I wanted to embed the iframe where the size of the iframe will also be the size of the vh. As an example I am hosting the html code for the link I am embedding and I need the height of the iframe to correspond to the 100vh that is referenced in the HTML code.

```
<iframe src='https://www.google.com' ></iframe>
```

vs.

```
<iframe src='https://www.google.com' width=?  height=? ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this : `<iframe src='https://www.google.com' style='width: 100%; height:100vh;margin: 0; padding: 0;'></iframe>` the iframe will automatically be adapted to your page

Answer (score 0):

You can set style for iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    iframe {
      height: 50vh;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
<body>
  <iframe src="iframe.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```